# AzureRMR object not found when set_tag() inside a function

Tags: r, azure

Running `set_my_tag(resources_to_tag)` gives error

> Error in eval(expr, p) : object 'resource' not found

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(AzureRMR)
#> Warning: package 'AzureRMR' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'AzureRMR'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     is_empty

set_my_tag <- function(resources_to_tag) {
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(resources_to_tag)) {
    resource <- resources_to_tag[i, ]
    
    az$
      get_subscription(resource$subscriptionid)$
      get_resource_group(resource$resourcegroup)$
      get_resource(type = resource$type, name = resource$name)$
      set_tags(MYTAG = resource$new_tag)
  }
  
}
resources_to_tag <-
  tribble(
    ~name, ~resourcegroup, ~subscriptionid, ~type, ~new_tag,
    "resource name", "resource group", "subscription id", "resource type", "new tag"
  )
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

While I do the following (not putting my code into a function) everything works fine.

```r
    resource <- resources_to_tag[1, ]

    az$
      get_subscription(resource$subscriptionid)$
      get_resource_group(resource$resourcegroup)$
      get_resource(type = resource$type, name = resource$name)$
      set_tags(MYTAG = resource$new_tag)
```

Moreover, and this is the strangest part, if I remove `set_tag()` from the `set_my_tag()` function it works fine:

```r
set_my_tag <- function(resources_to_tag) {
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(resources_to_tag)) {
    resource <- resources_to_tag[i, ]
    
    az$
      get_subscription(resource$subscriptionid)$
      get_resource_group(resource$resourcegroup)$
      get_resource(type = resource$type, name = resource$name)
  }
}

set_my_tag(resources_to_tag)
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `set_tags` uses `match.call` to get the unevaluated tagnames. When you pass it an expression, that expression has to be evaluated to get the actual tag. This runs into problems inside `set_tags` due to having to juggle parent frames.

A workaround is to use `eval(substitute(*))` to force the expression to be evaluated before calling `set_tags`:

```r
set_my_tag2 <- function(resources_to_tag)
{
    for(i in seq_len(nrow(resources_to_tag)))
    {
        resource <- resources_to_tag[i, ]
        tag <- resource$newtag
        obj <- az$
            get_subscription(resource$subscriptionid)$
            get_resource_group(resource$resourcegroup)$
            get_resource(type = resource$type, name = resource$name)
        eval(substitute(obj$set_tags(my_tag=.value), list(.value=resource$new_tag)))
    }
}
```

I'll fix this up for the next AzureRMR release. In hindsight, it would have been better to avoid all this NSE business....